# Fatal error: Allowed Memory Size of (X Size) when running drush migrate-upgrade

Tags: drush, migrations

I'm trying to use `drupal migration module` with `drush` to migrate a database. I'm getting this error below. 
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal-eight-iom/core/modules/migrate_drupal/src/Plugin/migrate/source/DrupalSqlBase.php on line 76

I have already tried editing the `memory_limit` on php.ini file

`memory_limit=5024MB`

Not sure what else I need to do in order to make it work. I'm using `Drupal 8.4.4`

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'drupal-eight-iom',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

$databases['upgrade']['default'] = array (
    'database' => 'drupal-seven-iom',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '3306',
    'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
  );


$settings['install_profile'] = 'standard';
$config_directories['staging'] = 'sites/default/config';
$config_directories['sync'] = 'sites/default/files/config_zB_DnNUK68i5Owp5a8FzTiClQfp3d3jrwcy0_HuS1hNCGv9Y_Iva2Ahm8LCH-P0j0M2jwmQAsA/sync';
```

Comment: 134217728 bytes is ~134mb, not 5024mb. Your memory limit override isn't taking effect. If you're on a shared host, they do that deliberately to stop people taking more than their fair share of resources

Comment: @Clive: He most probably isn't. I don't know any serious Shared Hosting providers using XAMPP. ;) - But to let me learn something as well: Would this question be considered Drupal Answers Off-Topic? My first guess was 'yes'...

Comment: Hah @Mario, I missed that ;) Yeah this is more of a general xampp issue than Drupal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check for the right `php.ini` file. Be aware, that drush is using the CLI (command line interface) version of PHP, which might use a different `php.ini` file than the version used by your web server.

Your above error message states, that the CLI version has a memory limit of 128MB only (which is the default value that might even be used when there is no php.ini file for your PHP version).

In Windows you can find out the used `php.ini` file - or the folder where it is expected - by typing the following command to your Windows command prompt:

`php -i | findstr /c:"php.ini"`

In Unix compatible systems you could use grep instead:

`php -i | grep "php.ini"`